# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined" while using module federation

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am using module federation to import a module from a remote and getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
at bootstrap.js:10
at lazyInitializer (react.development.js:1275)
at mountLazyComponent (react-dom.development.js:17662)
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19055)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994)
at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056)
at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964)
at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22779)
at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22707)
```

**Update:**

After hours of effort, I am able to identify the root cause of this error.

By changing the

```js
'react': { singleton: true, requiredVersion: deps.react },
```

to

```js
'react': { singleton: true },
```

the error is fixed. Looks like a webpack bug.